# How to decide which distribution a problem have?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I have the following task:

A company sells two types of cameras, Nikon and other types. The company also offers insurance. 3 of 10 carmeras sold were Nikon. 6 of the costumers wanted insurance. Assume that the probability that a costumer wants insurance is independent of the brand. Let X be the number of Nikon costumers who wanted insurance.

I need to find E[X] and Var[X].

At first I thought this was a hypergeometrical distribution, but then I saw that this problem has four different outcomes.

Any suggestions of what kind of distribution this type of problem follows?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Try Hyypergeometric again. I would say that you "take a sample" of $n=3$ out of $N=10$ clients, where $k=6$ has the special characteristic. I was led to this reasoning since you don't have probabilities for choosing a brand or taking insurance.

Comment: @RLC shouldn't n>k?

Comment: No. The only restriction is that $n,k\leq N$. Remember $n=$sample size, $N=$population size, $k=$number of members of the population with the interesting characteristic, $X=$number of objects of the sample (of size $n$) that have the characteristic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but this is what I got...

$X:$ number of customers who want insurance

$X$ can be $0,1,2$ or $3$

Need to find the probability of each occurrence.

$P$(customer wants insurance)$= \frac{6}{10}=\frac{3}{5}$

Binomial Distribution with $p=\frac{3}{5}$ and $n=3$:

$P(X=0)=\binom30(\frac{3}{5})^{0}(\frac{2}{5})^{3}=\frac{8}{125}$

$P(X=1)=\binom31(\frac{3}{5})^{1}(\frac{2}{5})^{2}=\frac{36}{125}$

$P(X=2)=\binom32(\frac{3}{5})^{2}(\frac{2}{5})^{1}=\frac{54}{125}$

$P(X=3)=\binom33(\frac{3}{5})^{3}(\frac{2}{5})^{0}=\frac{27}{125}$

To find $E(X)$ and $Var(X)$ use the following formulas:

$E(X)= \sum_{i} x_{i}P(x_{i})$

$=(0)(\frac{8}{125})+(1)(\frac{36}{125})+(2)(\frac{54}{125})+(3)(\frac{27}{125})=\frac{9}{5}=1.8$

$Var(X)= \sum_{i}P(x_{i})(x_{i}-E(X))^{2}$

$=(\frac{8}{125})(0-1.8)+(\frac{36}{125})(1-1.8)+(\frac{54}{125})(2-1.8)+(\frac{27}{125})(3-1.8)=\frac{18}{25}=0.72$